# How to hover transparent on selected element with background visible?

Tags: css

I have a list elements in td.. for td i just kept hover . When I click on particular element i am changing the background color of that particular element. But when I hover again i could not able to see wheather that selected one is selected or not. Now I want to hover on selected and unselected but when I go on to selected one i should find that element as selected.and rest are not selected.

```
    li:hover{
                background-color: #fff;
                color: #878787;

            }

$('li').on('click','.e',function(){
            if(!$(this).hasClass('activeList'))
            {
                $('.e').removeClass("es");
                $(this).addClass("es");
                var selectedEmpId = $(this).attr("eI");

            }
         });
```

Comment: Can you show your html or how do you change background color of `li`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This may help you](https://jsfiddle.net/harishkommuri/6wngbun0/)

```
li:not(.es):hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #878787;
}
.es {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

// script

$('li').on('click', function() {
  $('li').removeClass("es");
  $(this).addClass("es");
  var selectedEmpId = $(this).attr("eI");
});
```

Comment: can u add a  plunker please

Comment: Style `.es` as you need for active element and style for `li` for inactive elements